# Grouping with Linq only when all elements in a group have value in a column

Tags: c#, linq

I try to create groupings of lastReadings, where I can create client’s and competitor’s prices. I try below code, but this approach does not eliminate the readings that are only Client’s. With below table I need to eliminate the readingsId 5 and 6, for products C and D as there is no match and pass further only the comparable ones.

```
readingId   ProductId     Distributor   Price
1           A             Competitor    8.0
2           A             Client        8.1
3           B             Competitor    8.3
4           B             Client        8.4
5           C             Client        8.8
6           D             Client        8.9
```

Below is what I get so far:

```
    private IEnumerable<PriceComparison> getPriceComparisons(string competitor)
    {
        IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, LatestReading>> groupingsByProductId =
                            from latestReading in LatestReadings
                            group latestReading by latestReading.ProductId;


        IEnumerable<PriceComparison> priceComparisons
            = from grouping in groupingsByProductId
              select new PriceComparison
              {
                  ProductId = grouping.Key,
                  MyPrice = (from latestReading in grouping
                             where latestReading.Distributor == Client
                             select latestReading.Price).FirstOrDefault(),
                  CompetitorPrice = (from latestRading in grouping
                                     where latestRading.Distributor == competitor
                                     select latestRading.Price).FirstOrDefault()
              };
        return priceComparisons;
    }
```

Actually as I write this post, I concluded that for the additional created groupings with "no competitor", competitor price is there as 0, so later I can easily eliminate such groupings and the code works. But somehow this approach of creating "empty" groupings does not feel right, is there a better way to only focus on the groupings excluding products C and D?

Comment: If you have two readings for the same product, does that mean that one of them is for a client and the other for a competitor?

Comment: Yes, however there might be more competitors for the same product

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
//...

IEnumerable<PriceComparison> priceComparisons =
              from grouping in groupingsByProductId
              where grouping.Any(p => p.Distributor == Client)
                  && grouping.Any(p => p.Distributor == competitor)
              select new PriceComparison
              {
                 //..
              };
```

This makes sure that you get only the groups that have a price for both Client and Competitor.

Comment: works great, thank you Yacoub - some new weapon to my small Linq arsenal :)

Answer (score 2):

I think the [Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534675(v=vs.110).aspx) is more suitable for what you are trying to achieve, like this

```
var priceComparison = 
    from a in LatestReadings.Where(r => r.Distributor == Client)
    join b in LatestReadings.Where(r => r.Distributor == Competitor)
        on a.ProductId equals b.ProductId 
    select new PriceComparison
    {
        ProductId = a.ProductId,
        MyPrice = a.Price,
        CompetitorPrice = b.Price
    };
```

Comment: super, many thanks Ivan. I don't change my accept, just upvote your answer - but this is much simpler, yet one more eye opener today.

Comment: Please note that you would get multiple items for the same product id if there are more than one reading for Client or Competitor.

Comment: @YacoubMassad Correct. But I guess that's not the case here, otherwise `FirstOrDefault` in the original query would not make sense because it would compare randomly picked price for both client an competitor.